# Ubuntu replace PHP path

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, path, ampps

I have installed Ampps and then add `/usr/local/ampps/php/bin` to `/ect/environment` and when I rebooted my laptop everything worked out, after that I used `sudo apt-get install composer` and it installed dependencies on ubuntu including php, now my `php --ini` is showing path to `/usr/local/ampps/php/bin`

how can I change it back to ampps folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add new path like this:

```
vi ~/.bashrc
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/ampps/php/bin
```

You can edit path whatever you like

Comment: it worked, but I had to go with purge php7* and then this path was included to my path otherwise it was set on /opt... and i needed it to be in /usr/local...